# ConfigurationManager code fails when called from NUNIT project

Tags: c#, tdd, nunit

In my C# class project, I have a helper class which has the following property

```
public class Helper
{
    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

My following test fails when I call the Helper class from NUNIT project with error message: Failure: **System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
    [Test]
    public void connection_string_exists()
    {
        string connection = new Helper().ConnectionString;
        Assert.NotNull(connection);
    }
```

If I run the line of code **new Helper().ConnectionString** from a asp.net project then it works. Why does the Test fail?

Please let me know.

Comment: The .config file is found from the EXE name.  Which is not the usual one since nunit is running the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your Nunit tests are part of a different project and when you run the tests, ConfigurationManager looks at the config file of your test project and does not find "MyConnectionString"

Comment: Perhaps add a config file to your Nunit project and have a section <connectionString> which has the value. But then, the question really is, should there be a Unit Test just for this? I see your intent of writing the Unit Test for this, but I am not sure if this qualifies as a unit test case. Perhaps others could add their opinion for a wider view.

Comment: Agreed.  You are unit testing basic .net functionality.  Leave that to Microsoft to test.